# mysqldump via cmd syntax for dumping remote database

Tags: mysql, iis

I have Mysql installed on my local PC and want to use mysqldump on my local pc to dump a **remote database**. So I open CMD and run the following command:

```
mysqldump -P 3306 -h 12.43.33.43 -u admin -p myDatabase > mydb.sql
```

So in the next line it should ask for my password? but instead i get the response 'Access is denied'. Am i missing something here?

**ps.**

If I try the following:

```
mysqldump -P 3306 -h 12.43.33.43 -u admin -p myDatabase
```

it will successfully ask for my password and start printing the dump in cmd, but this is no good as i need the response saved in a file.

Comment: are you sure that you can access the database driectly. try to connect with workbench, usually you need a ssh tunnel to access the dataabse remotely

Comment: thats what I mean, if I do it using the second command it works fine so i do have access. I think there may a syntax issue with my top command?

Answer (score 0):

I  only wanted to know if you could connect.

The command is

```
mysqldump -P 3306 -h 12.43.33.43 -u admin -p --databases myDatabase --result-file=mydb.sql
```

As the connection is not secure, you send your credentials like a postcard, so that every one can read it.

Besides that having your server exposed to the internet, is very  **dangerous** and can come to a disaster, so reconsider your security strategy and allow only access via ssh.